# How to display faster shapes covering a country map?

Tags: shapefile, javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api

I need to display ~9000 polygons that represent country regions on a google map in a fast way. The polygons are kml formats (but I can get other formats too). At the moment everytime the map is displayed, the relative shapes are fetched out from a database. However there is a sort of delay which is not optimal. Is there anyway to avoid this database fetching or some optimisation maybe fully frontend side?

Comment: The polygons don't change, you could consider using a fixed image or something. I've run into a similar problem myself-- at some point, painting that many polygons server-side is just plain slow.

Comment: But how can I make them clickable then? With html

Comment: OK, in that case you really do need polygons. Images only work if they're fixed and you don't need clickability/etc. If your project is public, perhaps a link to it could help us debug?

Comment: Unfortunately it is not public. What about "hardcoding" the values inside javascript?

Comment: Do you need to view all the polygons when zoomed out really far or could you define a max zoom extent so they only draw when zoomed in closer?

Comment: No limits for the moment (actually I didnt think about that)

Answer (score 1):

Vector tiles could be the best solution, as you need the speed of the tiles but the vector properties of the polygons. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27284251/vector-tiles-with-google-maps-v3  might help.